# ScrollViewReader .scrollTo method doesn't allow padding when scrolling to TextField

Tags: ios, swiftui, uiscrollview, swift5, ios15

I'm using Xcode 13.2 and building for iOS 15.0 + with SwiftUI 3.0 and Swift 5

Here is my code:

```
ScrollViewReader { value in
  VStack {
    List(0..<things.count, id: \.self) { index in
      VStack {
        HStack {
          Image(systemName: "circle")

          TextField(
            "Text Field",
            text: $things[index]
          )
          .focused($focusField, equals: index)
          .submitLabel(.next)
          .onSubmit {
            funcThatScrollsToLastInput()
          }
        }
      }
      .padding(.bottom, 20)
      .id(index)

    }

  }

}
```

I have a ScrollView that on the return key, goes to the next TextField, which is great!

However, I cannot seem to add padding to the bottom of the TextField, nor to its wrapping HStack, VStack, or even if I add a rectangle, from within the confines of the stack that has the `.id(index)` modifier.

I want the TextField, when scrolled to, to have a `padding(.bottom)` of 10 or 20, but right now it's a 0.

It always seems to scroll exactly to the bottom the TextField *originally* had, or in other words without any style modifications.

Comment: I don't see an `ScrollView`in your code?

Comment: Doesn’t List work as well?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing padding for the amount of scrolling that has occurred as a result of your changing the `.focus()`. Your list rows have 20 padding on them. That is just the visual space around the view using other views away.

The issue you are having is that when you programmatically change the `.focus()` on a `TextField` in a `List`, the `TextField` is scrolled to high above the keyboard. You could have 0 or 100 padding, and that behavior would not change.

The fix is to finish implementing the `ScrollViewReader` and add a `.scrollTo()` in your code. Since you did not post  a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I just simply coded it in the `.onSubmit()`

```
              .onSubmit {
                  // I made focusField an optional, so I had to safely unwrap. If your implementation is
                  // non-optional, then you don't need this.
                  guard let focusField = focusField else {
                      return
                  }
                  if focusField < things.count - 1 {
                      self.focusField = focusField + 1
                      // The DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:) is necessary because the .scrollTo()
                      // has to wait for the .focus() to finish its scroll
                      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
                          // If your implementation of focusField is non-optional, then change this to
                          // focusField + 1 as the one below is a local constant, so the implementation
                          // uses focusField + 2 as you want the cell below the current cell to be in view/
                          value.scrollTo(focusField + 2, anchor: .bottom)
                      }
                  }
              }
```

Comment: The text Fields are being dynamically added, so focusedField + 2 might not exist? Sorry, might have forgot to mention that

Comment: Just realised my question is terrible, will update soon with an MRE, apologies for the subpar formatting

Comment: You don't need to edit your question. It won't matter. It can't scroll further than it has rows, but it won't crash it. It just scrolls to the end, and that view will be right above the keyboard, unless you manually tack an empty row on the end.

Comment: Ok, will figure something out. Thank you

Comment: Obviously, you are still confused. Where are you having an issue?

Comment: I understand that it's impossible since it can't scroll further than it has rows. That was what I wanted it, but decided to go another route since it is impossible unless I implement some hacky way to inset a fake TextField, hide it, add a blue re-appearing blue cursor on an above TextField pretending to be the one I want.